# Help With MultiThreadedExecutor

Tags: ros2

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
class MyNode : public rclcpp::Node {
  public:
    MyNode(const std::string node_name) : Node(node_name) {
        run();
    }


    void run() {
        // Run a loop with spin_some to process callbacks and maintain node activity
        while (rclcpp::ok()) {
            std::cout << node_name_ << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
            rclcpp::spin_some(this->get_node_base_interface());
            // Perform other tasks if needed
        }
    }

  private:
    std::string node_name_;
    rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr subscription_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    auto node1 = std::make_shared<MyNode>("node1");
    auto node2 = std::make_shared<MyNode>("node2");

    rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor executor;
    executor.add_node(node1);
    executor.add_node(node2);
    executor.spin();
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

can anyone tell me why node2 is not starting?

Answer (score 1):

The way you implemented it cannot work:

This `while` loop runs continuously until you press `ctrl+c`:

```cpp
while (rclcpp::ok()) {
  std::cout << node_name_ << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
  rclcpp::spin_some(this->get_node_base_interface());
  // Perform other tasks if needed
}
```

which means that the `run()` function is blocking and the constructor does not return untill you press `ctrl+c`:

```cpp
MyNode(const std::string node_name) : Node(node_name) {
 run();
}
```

Which means that large part of your code does not get executed until you press `ctrl+c`:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // This gets executed
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    // This calls the constructor, which hangs until you press `ctrl+c`
    auto node1 = std::make_shared<MyNode>("node1");
    // This only gets executed after you have pressed `ctrl+c`
    auto node2 = std::make_shared<MyNode>("node2");

    rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor executor;
    executor.add_node(node1);
    executor.add_node(node2);
    executor.spin();
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

You are not using executors and `spin_some` as they are intended.
Given the the use of executors and callback groups are commonly discussed topics, I suggest to read the official documentation as well as other tutorials online (just google, I did not keep specific references).

See also this [example repository](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/rolling/rclcpp/executors).

If you'd then still have specific questions wrt. that documentation or examples, post them here in a new question.

**EDIT:**

Really, you should study online documentation.

Anyway, here's a working example:

```cpp
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

class BlockingLoopNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  BlockingLoopNode(std::string name) : Node(name)
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Creating timer.");
    // The timer period is not important, its callback will only run once.
    timer_ = create_timer(
      1000ms, std::bind(&BlockingLoopNode::timer_callback, this));
  }


private:
  void timer_callback()
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Running timer callback.");
    while(rclcpp::ok()){
      wait_for_something_to_happen(3000);
      // do_other_stuff();
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Waited 3 second.");
    }
  }

  void wait_for_something_to_happen(unsigned int timeout_ms)
  {
    // E.g. wait on a socket, or for some event, etc.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(timeout_ms));
  }

  rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
};



int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  // As an example, we allow three threads for the executor:
  size_t number_of_threads = 3;
  rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor executor(rclcpp::ExecutorOptions(), number_of_threads);

  auto node1 = std::make_shared<BlockingLoopNode>("node1");
  executor.add_node(node1);

  auto node2 = std::make_shared<BlockingLoopNode>("node2");
  executor.add_node(node2);

  auto node3 = std::make_shared<BlockingLoopNode>("node3");
  executor.add_node(node3);

  auto node4 = std::make_shared<BlockingLoopNode>("node4");
  executor.add_node(node4);

  // Nodes 1, 2 and 3 will be spun. Each of their timer callbacks
  // will block one of the executor threads.
  // Node 4 will not be spun, as no threads are available
  // until one of the timer callbacks finishes, which they do not.
  executor.spin();

  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Do realize the following:

1. If you starve the nr. of Executor threads, no other callbacks will be run.

   E.g. if above node would also have a subscriber, and a message is received, then in above example the subscriber callback would *not* be executed as there are no threads left to execute it.
2. Even if you have extra Executor threads: all callbacks within a node default to one Mutually Exclusive CallbackGroup. 'Mutually exclusive' means that no other callback from that CallbackGroup will be started, while another callback from that CallbackGroup is still running. I.e. in above example, the Timer callback is blocking, so the subscriber callback would still not be called even if there are threads available. If you want a blocking callback and concurrently other callbacks, you will need to define a separate CallbackGroup for the other callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

https://github.com/ctu-mrs/ros2_examples/blob/master/src/publisher_example.cpp


In these examples they are using walltimers and subscribers, not functions with while loop

Comment: Obviously. ROS 2 executors execute timer/message/service callbacks, so if you want a 'function with while loop', you will need to call it from such a callback. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be achieved with threads.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    auto node1 = std::make_shared<MyNode>("node1");
    auto node2 = std::make_shared<MyNode>("node2");

    std::thread t1(&BlockingLoopNode::start, node1);
    std::thread t2(&BlockingLoopNode::start, node2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer@JRTF, can you also share insights on what are rthe benefit of using Executor over threads?

Comment: Well if you want your node to do ROS things (process messages / service request / parameter changes / etc.), then you will need to add it to an executor anyway. So I don't see a clear benefit of manually creating and joining the extra thread, while the MultiThreadedExecutor does that for you. Except maybe for the combination 'own thread + StaticSingleThreadedExecutor' which in some cases can be computationally more efficient than a MultiThreadedExecutor.